# Variable changes state to opposite if MSVS local variables window unfolds "this->base" view

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, debugging

I'm seriously confused by the way MSVS presents things to me regarding my boolean var

There's a button handler that triggers property change:

```
GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => purchasableItem.Active = true);
```

purchasableItem is a ScriptableObject;

```
 public bool Active
 {
     get
     {
         active = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(PrefName, prePurchased ? 1 : 0) != 0; 
         return active && Purchased;
     }
     set
     {
         active = value && Purchased;
         if (active)
         {
             foreach(var e in mutuallyExlusiveWith)
             {
                 e.Active = false;
             }
         }
         PlayerPrefs.SetInt(PrefName, active ? 1 : 0);
         Raise(active);
     }
 }
```

And here's the tricky part for me. When I break at "set", it seems like *active* variable gets equal "true" at line

```
active = value && Purchased;
```

It even gets into the "true" branch of the condition below, BUT! if I unfold "this->base" variable in MSVS, then debugger starts showing active as false in editor. And behave like it is false. What the?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eN9GF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjyIa.gif

PurchasableItem (base):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class PurchasableItem : ScriptableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    string prefName;
    [SerializeField]
    Sprite icon;
    [SerializeField]
    int price;
    [SerializeField]
    bool purchased;
    [SerializeField]
    bool prePurchased;
    [SerializeField]
    bool active;
    [SerializeField]
    PurchasableItem[] mutuallyExlusiveWith;

    List<PurchasableItemsListener> listeners = new List<PurchasableItemsListener>();

    public bool Purchased
    {
        get
        {
            purchased = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(PrefName + "Purchased", prePurchased ? 1 : 0) != 0;
            return purchased;
        }

        set
        {
            purchased = value;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(PrefName + "Purchased", purchased ? 1 : 0);
        }
    }

    public bool Active
    {
        get
        {
            active = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(PrefName, prePurchased ? 1 : 0) != 0; // Activate pre-purchased default effect in case of empty playerprefs during 1st run
            return active && Purchased;
        }
        set
        {
            active = value && Purchased;
            if (active)
            {
                foreach(var e in mutuallyExlusiveWith)
                {
                    e.Active = false;
                }
            }
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(PrefName, active ? 1 : 0);
            Raise(active);
        }
    }

    public void RegisterListener(PurchasableItemsListener listener)
    {
        listeners.Add(listener);
    }

    public void UnRegisterListener(PurchasableItemsListener listener)
    {
        listeners.Remove(listener);
    }

    void Raise(bool a)
    {
        foreach(var l in listeners)
        {
            l.OnActiveStatusEventRaised(a);
        }
    }

    public string PrefName { get => prefName; private set => prefName = value; }
    public int Price { get => price; private set => price = value; }
    public Sprite Icon { get => icon; set => icon = value; }
}
```

The inherited class is more or less empty.

```
public class PurchasableSkin : PurchasableItem
{
    public AnimatorOverrideController animOverride;
}
```

Comment: it will depend on the value of value and Purchased as to what happens to active

Comment: can you please debug the value of **active** after it is assigned.

Comment: @Ankit it is true right after assignment, but it becomes false immediately (on the same line of code) if I check the internal structure of this->base in the debugger. https://i.imgur.com/MsQJhwX.gif

Comment: @BugFinder value and Purchased are "true" as you can see on gif.

Comment: please edit your question and post your code, especially I' interested in your variable declaration, if it's a full class without any variable declarations missing (especially the global vars which are accessable from everywhere in your class) would grate.

Comment: Try commenting out everything but the first line of your ```set``` accessor and them debug the value of ```active```(both variable and your ```get``` accessor) just after your assignment statement. and let us know

Comment: @Ankit https://imgur.com/a/SKrMCvN edit post and also commented out everything else. Also, I kept the "this->base" inspector open from the start. Now *active* is never true.

Comment: @SergeyYakovlev try using condition instead. Like ```if(value && Purchased) active = true; else active = false;```

Comment: @Ankit https://imgur.com/ef1CuoX there is still the same strange misbehavior.

Comment: @SergeyYakovlev try ```this.active = true/false```. If this doesn't work as intended try creating a new get/set accessor. cause this is totally strange, and I've never experienced this before.

Comment: @Ankit tried that, no changes. Thanks for your time! I'll see how to rework this.

Comment: @SergeyYakovlev sorry that I'm not able to help you, good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on another forum.

> When you expand this->base, Visual Studio tries to display the values
>   of all of your fields **and properties**. In order for it to know the
>   value of a property, it has to call the "get" function for that
>   property.
>
> Active.get is changing the value of the field "active" based on your
>   PlayerPrefs, which hasn't yet been updated at the point where you
>   break.